# ImageJ & ffmpeg: How to create a video from a set of images using ffmpeg that can be opened by ImageJ?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, imagej, avi, fiji

I have a set of PNG images and want to create a video file from them that can be opened by ImageJ or Fiji. To do so I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i *.png -c:v ayuv -r 25 outvideo.avi
```

It works good, ImageJ\Fiji opens this video, but the resulted AVI is huge.

How to create a video with smaller size that can be opened by ImageJ\Fiji?

Comment: Maybe setting `-b` and/or `-q` would work, see for example https://superuser.com/questions/370058/ffmpeg-image2-avi-quality. You could use different codecs that do more compression, although I don't know what is and isn't supported by your viewers.

Comment: Not sure why you don't create a stack of your images in ImageJ and then save them as an AVI-video. ImageJ provides non-lossy PNG compression and no compression at all, as well as JPEG compression.

Comment: @Herbie can you explain, how to create a stack of images?

Comment: Let's assume your images are ordered in a folder, then go to "File >> Import >> Image Sequence...", look for the very folder and open as virtual stack. Save by "File >> Save As >> AVI...". Maybe you don't even need to save the stack as a video. Opening a stack as virtual stack means that only one frame is opened at a time. You can animate a stack by "Image >> Stacks >> Animation".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: Not agreed, because you missed the ImageJ-aspect of the question!

Comment: @Herbie arguably the ImageJ aspect of the question is _also_ not about programming, so that would make the question as a whole off-topic.

Comment: The reason that I've suggested the GUI-operation of stack- and video-creation doesn't mean that these operations aren't better implemented by the corresponding ImageJ-macro functions. It is important to note though that the GUI-operations can be recorded  as macro functions by using the macro-recorder of ImageJ and that's what should be done.

Answer (score 3):

For those who prefer to see code, here is the ImageJ-macro code that converts images in a directory to a JPG-compressed AVI-video:

```
dirImages=getDir("Choose a Directory");
File.openSequence(dirImages,"virtual");
run("AVI... ","compression=JPEG frame=25 save="+dirImages+"test.avi");
```

The video-file "test.avi" is saved to the directory of its images.